# Server Configuration Tool in IBM worklight V7 can not be started for z/Linux

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I installed IBM mobilefirst server on Liberty Profile in z/Linux(SUSE). I find the Server Configuration Tool can not be started, but it can be start in Windows7.

I want to know that Server Configuration Tool can not be started only in z/Linux or all platform(x86,AMD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server config tool is not available for z/Linux and AIX platforms. 
For these platforms the MFP configuration can be done using Ant task scripts instead.

The below link has the information about Creating and configuring the database for MobileFirst Server administration with Ant tasks and also
Deploying the MobileFirst Operations Console and Administration Services with Ant tasks 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/r_wlconsole_ant_tasks.html

Comment: Can the Server Configuration Tool be launched on Linux of other platform(x86,AMD) ?

Comment: Windows / Linux x86 / Mac OS x86. See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html

Comment: @jiangnan Yes the server configuration tool can be launched on other Linux Platforms like RHEL, SUSE (x86, AMD64) . Only for zLinux you require ant scripts.

Comment: @Sweta, do you have any plan to make it running on zLinux? To make the server configuration tool work on zLinux, do you need to re-compile existing code?